# Общение между программами

Tags: python, c++

Есть программа на C++ и скрипт на питоне. Питон осуществляет взаимодействие с пользователем (весь gui в скрипте, по-русски говоря). С++ получает данные и хранит в памяти, иногда сохраняя неиспользуемые на диске.

Что посоветуете?

Comment: >Что посоветуете ?

Неужели снова пайпы?

Comment: Если есть возможность, самое кошерное тут - переписать программу как бинарный модуль для питона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи есть несколько решений (гуглить межпроцессорное взаимодействие), если это дело работает на linux самое простое (как мне кажется) использовать Unix Domain Socket. Почти тот же сокет только локальный по свое природе. Данный подход используется много где, например в PostgreSQL.